# Rich text area not allowing to select font

Tags: visualforce

I have a visual force page where rich text area is used.

[image]

In the text area can't able to select the font. Need option to select fonts.Any idea?

Comment: I don't think standard Salesforce rich text area provides that functionality. I have seen rich text fields on standard layouts and they don't have options to choose the text font. I have tried using API v34

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an outputText field? You'll need to set 'escape=false'

Comment: its is input text area with richtext <apex:inputTextarea value="{!htmlEmailBody}" id="bodyId" title="Body" richText="true" />

Comment: This is the  link to the Idea Exchange : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000JI8BAAW

Comment: This one is somehow related to it . https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrJz